# Gmail doesn't respond with TAG OK via IMAP on successful login

Tags: email, gmail, protocols, imap

Here's its response gotten via socket in my application:

```
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT APPENDLIMIT=35882577 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS
```

when login is successful on the port 993. Here's is one when a login or password is wrong on the same port:

```
TAG_2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Where's OK and Tag in the 1st case?

Comment: Read another line.  There can be more than one response.

Comment: @Max, it must be in the 1st line.

Comment: No, it mustn't.  Full answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IMAP server is allowed, and will, provide multiple responses to a command.  In this case, Gmail is providing an unsolicited `CAPABILITY` response, so you don't have to request it yourself later.

Sample session from gmail:

```
> a LOGIN user password
< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT APPENDLIMIT=35882577 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS
< a OK user authenticated (Success)
```

LOGIN is just like any other command, it can have several responses, just like SELECT has *many* responses before finishing:

```
> b SELECT INBOX
< * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Junk $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing Junk NonJunk NotJunk)
< * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Junk $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing Junk NonJunk NotJunk \*)] Flags permitted.
< * OK [UIDVALIDITY 636588758] UIDs valid.
< * 271 EXISTS
< * 0 RECENT
< * OK [UIDNEXT 24821] Predicted next UID.
< * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 917752]
< b OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
```

You should simply continue reading lines until you receive the *tagged* response to your query.  Any untagged responses (starting with *) are informative, and can be ignored or processed as required.

This particular behaviour, sending `CAPABILITY` on LOGIN is expressly allowed by RFC 3501, section 7.2.1:

```
  A server MAY send capabilities automatically, by using the
  CAPABILITY response code in the initial PREAUTH or OK responses,
  and by sending an updated CAPABILITY response code in the tagged
  OK response as part of a successful authentication.  It is
  unnecessary for a client to send a separate CAPABILITY command if
  it recognizes these automatic capabilities.
```

Please also see section 2.2.2, which indicates: 
`A client MUST be prepared to accept any server response at all times. This includes server data that was not requested.`

Comment: Although, this can also be sent as `tag OK [CAPABILITY ...]`, which is also seen in the wild.

Comment: where does it state that it can provide Tag Ok on a 2nd line?

Comment: It can provide as many responses as it likes before the tagged OK.  That's how IMAP works.  All IMAP commands can provide untagged responses before returning a tagged response.  There's a small exception for EXPUNGE responses during certain commands due to data consistency issues.

Comment: You should probably ask yourself where does the RFC state that it may NOT return additional responses?

Comment: Section 2.2.2: Data transmitted by the server to the client and status responses
   that do not indicate command completion are prefixed with the token
   "*", and are called untagged responses.

   Server data MAY be sent as a result of a client command, or MAY be
   sent unilaterally by the server.  There is no syntactic difference
   between server data that resulted from a specific command and server
   data that were sent unilaterally.

Comment: it can return additional responses, RFC states that.

Comment: Also in same section:  A client MUST be prepared to accept any server response at all times.
   This includes server data that was not requested.